# How to add elements from user input into an array while looping?

Tags: arrays, mips

I asked the user for the size of the array. Then I loop in range of the size with asking the user for an integer each time, and add the value into the array.

I tried to do code similar to 4($t1) except I replace the '4' to a register. I realised it can't be a register, but I don't know how to do it in other ways.

```
#store element into array
addi $v0, $0, 5 #ask user for element
syscall
lw $t1, i
addi $t3, $t1, 1
li $t4, 4
mult $t1, $t4
mflo $t0 #load
sw $v0, $t0($t8) #store user input into array <<<<<LINE WITH ERROR>>>>>
addi $t1, $t1, 1 #increment i
```

I expect the user input to be stored in $t8, but it gives me error message '"$t0": operand is of incorrect type'. I think it's because I used a register instead of number. Please help!

Comment: How is this a `python` related question? Are you trying to recreate python code in MIPS?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: `sw $v0, $t0($t8)` is not a legal MIPS instruction, because you can't use `$t0($t8)`. Try `add $t9,$t0,$t8`, `sw $v0,$t9`